# Additive AutoFilter - Workaround

Tags: excel, vba, filter, filtering

I'm trying to filter a column in an excel file using vba code, but the problem is that I can't save the first filter and add another one (different IF conditions). How can I save the first filter and add a second one in the same column ?

Thanks a lot!

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

    If InStr(TextBox1.Text, "TEST_1") Then
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A$1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("B", "C", _
                                    "D", "E"), _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With

        If InStr(TextBox1.Text, "TEST_2") Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("A$1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="F"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First check the conditional, if it's true then add the value to your array and filter only by the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot Damian ! It's working fine :)

Comment: @Damian can you put that in an answer so this can be marked as closed-answered?

Answer (score 0):

Checking first all the conditions will allow you to build up the array you need to then use it as filter.